# Broken RStudio, VLC, and other apps because of Qt incompatibility on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, qt

I updated my system to use the lastest RStudio version, which required to install Qt from Qt's website (https://d13lb3tujbc8s0.cloudfront.net/onlineinstallers/qt-unified-linux-x64-4.2.0-online.run), and I installed Qt Web Creator 5.12.8.

Even after removing ~/Qt and no remaining environment variables, I can't open RStudio, VLC or other software, and when opening applications from the terminal I read

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50c0a) with this library (version 0x50c08)
```

I've tried to purge all the Qt packages installed via apt-get and reinstall and the error persists.

Comment: Usually, when you have two libs installed, one for a specific application, you can call the libraries when you run the application. You can do this by setting the variables before the command on the same command line like this example: `something=VARIABLE command` This way, the variable isn't set for other apps and the default libs still work for everything else. This is strange though because you've removed everything.

Comment: You are making future system maintenance difficult. You have to stick with Qt from official repositories and live without problems. If you you need Qt4 - use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4/), if you need newer Qt5 - use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt-5.15.2-focal).

Answer (score -1):

My solution to get VLC working again (and other binary software)

```
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo rm -rf libQt*
sudo apt install qt5-default qtcreator qtwebengine5-dev libqt5sensors5-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev
sudo apt purge vlc
sudo apt install vlc
```