# Build RStudio on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: rstudio

Related to [Broken RStudio, VLC, and other apps because of Qt incompatibility on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394225/broken-rstudio-vlc-and-other-apps-because-of-qt-incompatibility-on-ubuntu-20-0/1394246#1394246)

I am trying to build RStudio with accessibility options, which requires a regular build:

```
git clone git@github.com:rstudio/rstudio.git
cd rstudio
mkdir build && cd build
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/ /usr/local/bin/
cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Desktop -DRSTUDIO_PACKAGE_BUILD=1 -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/qmake
```

The make install fails because it can't find libicu

```
[  2%] Built target rstudio-shared-core
[  4%] Built target rstudio-core-hunspell
[ 25%] Built target rstudio-core
[ 26%] Built target rstudio-session-workers
[ 26%] Built target rstudio-core-synctex
[ 27%] Built target rstudio-monitor
[ 33%] Built target rstudio-r
[ 75%] Built target rsession
[ 75%] Built target gwt_build
[ 76%] Built target rstudio-shared-core-tests
[ 82%] Built target rstudio-core-tests
[ 82%] Built target diagnostics
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/lib/libicui18n.so', needed by 'src/cpp/desktop/rstudio'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:728: src/cpp/desktop/CMakeFiles/rstudio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:152: all] Error 2
```

I find it strange to point to `/usr/lib/lib/`, which is a directory that doesn't exist.

Comment: A debian installer is available. You don't need to compile from source. https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download

Comment: You are making future system maintenance difficult. You have to stick with Qt from official repositories and live without problems. If you you need Qt4 - use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4/), if you need newer Qt5 - use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt-5.15.2-focal).

Comment: i want to build with accessibility options

Comment: Then use docker https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/main/docker/docker-compile.sh  instead of trashing working systems and give bad recommendations here in public place.

Answer (score 1):

My own solution, knowing that libicu-dev is installed

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so /usr/lib/lib/libicudata.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so /usr/lib/lib/libicuuc.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so /usr/lib/lib/libicui18n.so
sudo make install
```

result

```
[  2%] Built target rstudio-shared-core
[  4%] Built target rstudio-core-hunspell
[ 25%] Built target rstudio-core
[ 26%] Built target rstudio-session-workers
[ 26%] Built target rstudio-core-synctex
[ 27%] Built target rstudio-monitor
[ 33%] Built target rstudio-r
[ 75%] Built target rsession
[ 75%] Built target gwt_build
[ 76%] Built target rstudio-shared-core-tests
[ 82%] Built target rstudio-core-tests
[ 82%] Built target diagnostics
[100%] Built target rstudio
[100%] Built target rpostback
```

Comment: The `/usr/lib/lib/` path looks strange. Do invent bicycles! Use official debian package from https://rstudio.org/download/latest/stable/desktop/bionic/rstudio-latest-amd64.deb . You will get 2021.09.2+382 which is latest stable.

Comment: i want to build with accessibility options